# Using one model to read and another to save data

Tags: cakephp, save

I have a model named `google_news.php` which uses the external data, and another model `saved_news.php` which uses my saved_news table in database,

In my controller I declared that Im using this two models:

```
var $uses = array('GoogleNews', 'SavedNews');
```

and my index function reads data:

```
$this->set('news',$this->GoogleNews->find('all'));
```

and my view looks like this:

```
<?php foreach( $news as $newsItem ) : ?>

<?php echo $html->link($newsItem['GoogleNews']['title'], array('action'=>'add',    $newsItem['GoogleNews']['title'])); ?>

<?php echo $newsItem['GoogleNews']['encoded']; ?>

<em>
<hr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

How to write the add function in my controller to save each data to my database?

Comment: your question seems confusing. Have you ran through the Blog tutorial yet?

Answer (score 0):

You should assign what you need to be saved into $this->data['ModelName'] as array of fields.  Take a look at [saving data](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data) in the book.  That will explain more about the formatting that needs to be followed.